# expect returning error "Option requires an argument" when argument given

Tags: macos, expect

I have this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "upload" == $1 ];then
expect -c <<'END_EXPECT'
set timeout -1
spawn sftp -i /Users/myuser/.ssh/private.key root@dev.site.org
expect "sftp>"
send "put dirname $0/$2/$3 /var/www/localhost/htdocs/dev1.site.org/$2/$3\r"
expect "%100"
send "quit\r"
expect eof
END_EXPECT
elif [ 'download' == $1 ];then
expect -c <<'END_EXPECT'
set timeout -1
spawn sftp login_name@1.2.3.4
expect "[Pp]assword:"
send "login_password\r"
expect "sftp>"
send "get /remote_path/$2/$3 dirname $0/$2/$3 \r"
expect "%100"
send "quit\r"
expect eof
END_EXPECT
fi
```

However, it is throwing this error:

```
expect: option requires an argument -- c
usage: expect [-div] [-c cmds] [[-f] cmdfile] [args]
```

I'm in OSX 10.9. Why it is not working? I've never used expect in the past...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take out `-c` when passing the expect script in a here-doc

---

Additionally, you're quoting the here-doc terminator word: `<<'END_EXPECT'`
That means that the shell variables embedded inside it **will not** get expanded.
You'll have a problem with this:

```
send "put dirname $0/$2/$3 /var/www/localhost/htdocs/dev1.site.org/$2/$3\r"
```

when expect complains about `can't read "2": no such variable`, etc

Here's a rewrite, fixing the here-doc problem, your "dirname" problem and adding indentation for clarity:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "upload" == "$1" ];then
    expect <<END_EXPECT
        set timeout -1
        spawn sftp -i /Users/myuser/.ssh/private.key root@dev.site.org
        expect "sftp>"
        send "put $(dirname $0)/$2/$3 /var/www/localhost/htdocs/dev1.site.org/$2/$3\r"
        expect "%100"
        send "quit\r"
        expect eof
END_EXPECT
elif [ 'download' == "$1" ];then
    expect <<END_EXPECT
        set timeout -1
        spawn sftp login_name@1.2.3.4
        expect "[Pp]assword:"
        send "login_password\r"
        expect "sftp>"
        send "get /remote_path/$2/$3 $(dirname $0)/$2/$3 \r"
        expect "%100"
        send "quit\r"
        expect eof
END_EXPECT
fi
```

---

Additionally, you may not need expect at all:

```
case "$1" in
    upload)
        cmd="put $(dirname $0)/$2/$3 /var/www/localhost/htdocs/dev1.site.org/$2/$3"
        ;;
    download)
        cmd="get /remote_path/$2/$3 $(dirname $0)/$2/$3"
        ;;
esac
echo "$cmd" | sftp -i /Users/myuser/.ssh/private.key root@dev.site.org
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... you are right. There is no need to use expect at all. I have submitted one issue to the github site of the plugin I'm using (http://bit.ly/1rovgaF)

Comment: question: is there a way to get the ssh connection alive? My server has a limitation of 5 max connections from the same server in a window of 600 seconds. So for development this is not useful... How to keep the connection alive and re-use it later? Thanks if you can help me with this...

Comment: Highly recommend you ask a new question so other people will see it. First thing that comes to mind is to talk to your sysadmin.

Comment: Thanks Glenn.. Actually I manage the server, so I increase the number of connections... but that is not a good practice, and I don't like it... I'll do it. Thanks!